# custom post type, hide or disable the trash button in publish meta box

Tags: custom-taxonomy, trash

[image]

I have been adding a post type to my theme, how do I hide/disable the Move to trash button?
Here is my code so far:

```
$labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Inhoud', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Inhoud', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Zoek Inhoud' ),
        // 'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Writers' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'Alle Inhoud' ),
        'parent_item'                => null,
        'parent_item_colon'          => null,
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Wijzig Inhoud' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update Inhoud' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Toevoegen Nieuwe Inhoud' ),
        // 'new_item_name'              => __( 'Nieuwe Evenement Naam' ),
        // 'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate writers with commas' ),
        // 'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove writers' ),
        // 'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used writers' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'Geen inhoud gevonden.' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Inhoud' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => false,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        //'show_admin_column'     => true,
        //'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
    'menu_position'     => 7,
    'menu_icon'         => 'dashicons-admin-post',
    'show_in_menu'      => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
    'show_in_admin_bar' => false,
        // 'query_var'         => true,
        // 'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'inhoud' ),
    'capabilities'      => array( 
                            'create_posts'  => 'do_not_allow',
                            //'edit_post'   => 'true',
                            //'delete_posts'   => 'do_not_allow'
                          ),
    'supports'          => array( ),
    'map_meta_cap'      => array('delete_post' => false),
    'has_archive'       => true,
    'public'            => true
    );

    register_post_type( 'inhoud', $args );
```

Comment: Has this question been resolved? Did my answer help?

Comment: I've forgot to respond on this question, I gave you some points for a solution ;-) But went for the other one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide move to trash button via adding css in the admin area. Try following code in `functions.php` file:

```
function my_custom_admin_styles() {
?>
    <style type="text/css">
      .post-type-inhoud form #delete-action{
           display:none;
       }
     </style>
<?php
}
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_admin_styles');
```

Answer (score 3):

Tested out the code that was provided by [user3888958](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/101627/user3888958), but didn't work for me. here's my own version which hide the *Move to Trash* link:

```
add_action( 'admin_head', 'wpse_237305_disable_trash' );

function wpse_237305_disable_trash() {
    global $pagenow;

    if ( $pagenow == 'post.php' ) {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
                $( '#delete-action' ).remove();
            } );
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
```

#### Result

[image]